# PHP - checkbox form wont return itself as clicked

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a variable called present, I also have a checkbox, I need to make it so that if the checkbox is checked, then someone submits the form, the `$present` variable will change to a value of 1. Right now nothing happens if the box is checked, if I change it from

```
if(isset($_POST['stud_attendance']))
```

to

```
if(!isset($_POST['stud_attendance']))
```

then it will work, because else sets the `$present` variable to one, but for some reason the code just isn't realizing that the checkbox is checked.

Below is my code:

```
$present = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";

    echo "<td>";

    echo $row[6];

    ?>

 //below is the code****************************************************

    <input type="checkbox" name="stud_attendance" value="0">

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['stud_attendance']))
{
$present = 1;
}
else
{

 $present = 0;

}

// above is the code ******************************

    echo $present;
// above is just to check the value of the variable
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$row[5]."</td>";

    echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You need to use the `form` tag. Wrap your checkbox code in: `<form method='post' action=''></form>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript, something like this in a submit input:

```
onclick="if(this.value=='0') this.value='1'"
```

But that input should be surrounded by a form.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can check what is in post array:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

If checkbox is checked it should be present as:

```
...
[stud_attendance] => on
...
```

otherwise it will be not present in $_POST array.

Comment: The value of `stud_attendance` should actually show as 0 if it's checked, since the checkbox has a value attribute.  But it's still a good idea to make sure $_POST actually contains the right stuff.  (The comment about the form tag, on the question itself, is starting to seem more and more relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your <form> tag in your code snippet. Make sure you have method="post" or it'll default to a get request. You could also just switch from $_POST to $_GET or $_REQUEST. If that's not it, it would help to post more of your code.